# TypeScript/ES6 Modules: Is it possible to both import and re-export in a single statement?

Tags: typescript

Here's my scenario. I am importing a TypeScript interface, providing it with a local name, using it locally, and also re-exporting it with the same local name. In order to do achieve this, I have both an `import` statement and an `export` statement with an identical local name and path. So I'm curious if might be possible to combine these statements somehow.

```
// \app\models\FilterIdValue.ts
export interface FilterIdName {
    filterId: number;
    name: string;
}

// \app\components\FilterIdName.tsx
import { FilterIdName as FilterIdNameProps } from '../models/FilterIdValue' 
export { FilterIdName as FilterIdNameProps } from '../models/FilterIdValue'
// Can the import and export be combined somehow?

export interface FilterIdNameListProps {
    items: FilterIdNameProps[];
}

export default class FilterIdNameList extends React.Component<FilterIdNameListProps, any> {
    constructor(props: FilterIdNameListProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        var items = this.props.items.map(item => (
                <FilterIdName filterId={item.filterId} name={item.name} />
        ));   
        return (<div>{items}</div>);
    }
}

// \app\components\FilterIdNameList.tsx
import FilterIdName, { FilterIdNameProps } from './FilterIdName'
//...
```

One reason for doing this is to have a single import statement in a downstream object (with the aliased local name predefined and with the relative path maintained in one location).

From perusing [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/), I gather that this is not possible. But I'm curious if there is another way to prevent maintenance of the extra statement (alias and path).

Comment: no.. it doesn't look like it's possible to import and export with an alias in a single statement. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Although there are other ways to achieve this same effect, you will always need two statements.